# Why there is no option in default country "India" in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have been facing a problem since today that there is no option in drop down list **default country**  **"India"** .It is **Indi** .Why there is not available **India**.

---

[image]

Is there any solution?It would be helpful for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

Step1: Open lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml

Step2: Go to line no 799 and change the value from "Indi" to "India".

Cheers!!!

Comment: In my cases it not work if i change any country name here it not reflect in fronted.